# How do I prove that an object does not interpret a locale?

Tags: isabelle

I want to define "big" natural numbers as those larger than 10, and "small" ones as those less than 5. I can express these definition as locales:

```
locale Big = 
  fixes k :: ‹nat›
  assumes ‹k > 10›

locale Small =
  fixes k :: ‹nat›
  assumes ‹k < 5›
```

I can then prove that 11 is a Big number and 2 is a Small one:

```
interpretation Big ‹11 :: nat› by (unfold_locales, simp)
interpretation Small ‹2 :: nat› by (unfold_locales, simp)
```

But how would I express and prove that 7 is not Small? I can prove that it is not less than 5, but the proof is unsatisfactory since it does not refer to the locale Small at all:

```
lemma ‹¬ ((7 :: nat) < (5 :: nat))› by simp
```

Moreover, how would I express that no integer exists which is both Big and Small? Again, I can prove it, but only without reference to the locales:

```
lemma
  fixes k :: nat
  shows ‹¬ (k < 5 ∧ k > 10)›
  by simp
```

In general, how do I prove that something is not an interpretation of one or more locales? Or am I misusing the locale mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `locale` is documented in Isar-ref and the document "Tutorial to Locales and Locale Interpretation". Also, there has been a number of relevant publications that describe the implementation/syntax in more detail and in a more formal manner. One document that comes to my mind is [Locales and Locale Expressions in Isabelle/Isar](http://www21.in.tum.de/~ballarin/publications/types2003.pdf) by Clemens Ballarin. It is outdated, but (in my view) it provides more elaborate explanation of the fundamental concepts than Isar-ref and the tutorial. In particular, see section 3.3: "Locale Predicates and the Internal Representation of Locales" in the aforementioned document.

---

> But how would I express and prove that 7 is not Small? I can prove
>   that it is not less than 5, but the proof is unsatisfactory since it
>   does not refer to the locale Small at all:

Using the locale predicates, you may state the theorem in your question as follows:

```
lemma "¬Small 7" unfolding Small_def by auto
```

Whether or not using a locale predicate explicitly is sensible and whether there exist better options for expressing a given idea depends on the context.

---

> Moreover, how would I express that no integer exists which is both Big
>   and Small?

```
lemma "¬(Small x ∧ Big x)" unfolding Small_def Big_def by simp
```

The main conclusion from the above is that locale predicates (e.g. `Small`) are merely constants and the command `locale` provides several theorems about these constants, including their definition (e.g. `Small_def`). The referenced documents provide further details.

---

> In general, how do I prove that something is not an interpretation of
>   one or more locales? Or am I misusing the locale mechanism?

Unfortunately, in my view, these questions require clarification. Overall, the decision whether a locale, a class or a plain definition should be used to define a given concept depends on the application and, to a degree, on personal preferences.

Comment: Very comprehensive and helpful; excellent reference, thanks! Can you recommend something to look at to better understand when to use locales, classes, or plain definitions?

Comment: @SørenDebois I am not aware of any official guides. In my opinion, this is, primarily, a matter of personal preference. However, similar questions have been asked in the past on the mailing list, e.g. see https://lists.cam.ac.uk/mailman/htdig/cl-isabelle-users/2014-August/msg00237.html. I guess, the best guide for this is the standard library of Isabelle/HOL, as it showcases good practices via examples. Of course, reading relevant sections in the documentation and tutorials should also help to form your own opinion.